# Find record which doesn't have any associated records with a specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a couple of models: User and UserTags

```
A User has_many UserTags
A UserTag belongs_to User
```

I am trying to find all the `Users` which don't have a `UserTag` with name 'recorded' (so I also want users which don't have any tags at all). Given a users relation, I have this:

```
users.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN user_tags ON user_tags.user_id = users.id AND user_tags.name = 'recorded'").
where(user_tags: { id: nil })
```

Is there any other better or more Railsy way of doing this?

Comment: I think what you've got so far is probably the cleanest approach to get what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
users.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN user_tags ON user_tags.user_id=users.id").where("user_tags.name != ? OR user_tags.id is NULL", 'recorded')
```

Comment: We got the same idea, a minute apart :D

Comment: This would not return users that don't have any tags.

Comment: @HommerSmith I have updated the answer and it should return you all the records from left table which are either not associated or which are satisfying the condition.

Comment: @dkp why not using eager_loading using `includes`?? which also provide left outer join

Comment: @VishalJAIN `includes` will do the work but is there really any need of selecting columns from both the tables ? If I only need `users` table data, I would get that using `joins`.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
users.joins(:user_tags).where.not(user_tags: { name: 'recorded' })
```

Comment: This would not return users that don't have any tags

Comment: You'll need to keep your left join then, and replace it accordingly in the query above :).

Comment: @born4new you are right for left outer join best way to use is eager_load.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will return the users with 0 user_tags :

```
users = users.joins(:user_tag).where("users.id IN (?) OR user_tags.name != ?",User.joins(:user_tag).group("users.id").having('count("user_tag.user_id") = 0'), "recorded")
```

Answer (score 0):

Joins not eager load nested model you should use "Includes or eage_load"

```
 users.eager_load(:user_tags).where.not(user_tags: { name: 'recorded' })
```

This will use left outer join and you can update your query in where clause.
Same as

```
users.includes(:user_tags).where.not(user_tags: { name: 'recorded' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can simply use `includes` for outer join as `user_tags.id is null` returns all your record not having `user_tags` and `user_tags.name != 'recorded'` returns record having user_tag name is not `recorded`

```
users.includes(:user_tags).where("user_tags.id is null or user_tags.name != ?","recorded")
```

Or you can also used using `not in` clause as but it is not optimised way for given query:

```
users.includes(:user_tags).where("users.id not in (select user_id from user_tags) or user_tags.name != ?","recorded")
```

Comment: `!= 'recorded'` this will create a security issue make it `sanitize`